# Safari browser bookmarks vanish

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks, osx-leopard

I have a big problem with Bookmarks in Safari on Mac OS X 10.5. The following problem occurs:

When I try to save for example www.greatsite.com as a Bookmark through *Bookmarks/Add Bookmark...* then the Bookmarked site won't show up in the Bookmarks drop down Menu. But when I go to *Bookmarks/show all bookmarks* then I can see the Bookmarked site www.greatside.com.

The Bookmarked site doesn't vanish completely but it doesn't show up in the drop down Menu of the Bookmarks section. I want to add that I have a whole lot of Bookmarks (∼1000).

Answer (score 1):

You must add the book marked page to a folder that is displayed in your book mark bar in order for it to show up in the drop down on the book mark bar. Not all folders are included in the bar. You can drag and drop saved book marks into safari through the bookmark/showall window including folders for large volume imports